# Rendering some data on EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**FIXED IT**

I'm a little bit confused about rendering some data that I'm fetching from my mongo database.

The returned data is the following:

```
[ { _id: { year: 2018, month: 6 }, sum: 4005 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 7 }, sum: 43 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 5 }, sum: 3996 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 4 }, sum: 434 } ]
```

I'm able to render sum, but I'm confused because when I try to render year and month, there's something like "several definitions" I guess that it's something related to JS itself, and because of that I'm not being able to render the year and month on my table.

The code on the view is this one:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Atendimentos</th>
    <th>Mês</th>
    <th>Ano</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <% for(var i=0; i<back.length; i++) { %>
    <td><%=  back[i].sum %></td>
    <td><%= back[i].month %></td>
    <td><%= back[i].year %></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

The sum is rendering correctly, but the year and month fields are in blank.

What should I do to render month and year?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I didn't see that the year and month were inside the id {}.